# A command to add a customized icon or symbol to Plasma's Default Panel

Tags: kde, command-line, plasma

Is there a command, that can add/remove a simple icon in KDE environment tray or anywhere in plasma's Panel (taskbar)?

I need a customized notification icon or any other persistent symbol which shows a customized condition is on or off. (for me, it will show whether a network cable traffic is limited or is free)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you entirely, but do you mean something that tests some parameter, then displays different icons depending on the result? If so, then perhaps [STDIN Plasmoid](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/STDIN+Plasmoid?content=92309) might help?

Comment: It seems STDIN is the same as a shortcut except it shows the output of a command. But what I need is a multistate icon which will choose its state by instructions it receives from a command executed anywhere. for instance I'll be able to open a terminal and type something like `iconstate 2` and the icon will change.

Comment: That could work though, as long as you don't mind a text-based "icon". You could define a command where `iconstate 2` writes "2" to `/tmp/iconstate`, then set STDIN up to read from `/tmp/iconstate` and change its (text) output accordingly.

Comment: yes works somewhat good. thanks. by the way time-based refresh which can engage CPU and just text output seems bad. It could be perfect if it could receive refresh commands.

Comment: Yeah, I agree in the general case. However, I think the CPU usage is pretty slight here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to archive an answer.

Thanks to [Sparhawk](https://askubuntu.com/users/53508/sparhawk) I could add something in  Panel which shows the state of a connection.
I have scripts for limiting a connection:
[image]

each can be run by quicklaunch shortcuts located in panel.

For example 64kbits can contain something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

wondershaper eth0 64 64 

echo 64 > /home/Walesa/mycommands/kbits/state.txt
```

But running each script should show a persistent easy to see sign, so that the user knows about the limitation. With [STDIN](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/STDIN+Plasmoid?content=92309) widget the contents of `state.txt` can be displayed:

[image]

Here 32 shows the connection has speed 32 kbits. `state.txt` is what the scripts prepare. But the widget checks its contents every 30 seconds. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: Just a reminder that you can now accept this answer. There's nothing against accepting your own answer (it's encouraged actually), you can't do it in the 1st 24 hours after posting it.

Comment: `Just for record. Not an ideal solution` can prevent. Also I hope someone appears with a better answer, an unanswered question may be more encouraging. btw, you may concern askubuntu's statistics. I'll have to make a minor sacrifice to improve it :)